# Adding an existing field to an existing FIX message

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am trying to add the [OnBehalfOfCompID](https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/tagNum_115.html) field to the [ExecutionReport](https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.4/msgType_8_8.html) message for the Fix Protocol, however my code is throwing an error of `QuickFix.FieldNotFoundException: field not found for tag: 115` when attempting to retrieve the value of this new field.

My DataDictionary is as follows:

```
<message name='ExecutionReport' msgcat='app' msgtype='8'>
...
 <field name='OnBehalfOfCompID' required='N' />
...
</message>
```

I also manually modified our `FixLibV3.Messages.Fix50SP2.ExecutionReport.generated.cs` to include the OnBehalfOfCompID details:

```
/// <summary>
/// Tag 115 of type STRING->StringField. Optional.
/// </summary>
public Fields.OnBehalfOfCompID OnBehalfOfCompID
{
    get
    {
        var v = new Fields.OnBehalfOfCompID();
        GetField((StringField)v);
        return v;
    }
    set { SetField(value); }
}

/// <summary>
/// Tag 115
/// </summary>
public void Set(Fields.OnBehalfOfCompID v)
{
    OnBehalfOfCompID = v;
}

/// <summary>
/// Tag 115
/// </summary>
public Fields.OnBehalfOfCompID Get(Fields.OnBehalfOfCompID v)
{
    GetField((StringField)v);
    return v;
}

/// <summary>
/// Tag 115
/// </summary>
public bool IsSetOnBehalfOfCompID()
{
    return IsSetField(Fields.Tags.OnBehalfOfCompID);
}

/// <summary>
/// Tag 115
/// </summary>
public bool IsSet(Fields.OnBehalfOfCompID v)
{
    return IsSetOnBehalfOfCompID();
}
```

When I try and retrieve the value for `OnBehalfOfCompID` with

```
 _executionReport.GetString(Fields.Tags.OnBehalfOfCompID);
```

or even with

```
_executionReport.OnBehalfOfCompID.getValue();
```

I get the error:

```
'_executionReport.OnBehalfOfCompID' threw an exception of type 'QuickFix.FieldNotFoundException'
```

During debug I can clearly see that the field `115`exists in the string representation of the message. How do I successfully pull the value from the message? What am I missing?

Comment: Can I see the message?  Normally, `OnBehalfOfCompID` is in the header.  It seems odd that you're trying to put it in the ExecutionReport body.  Is it possible you've misunderstood something in your requirement?

Comment: Thanks @GrantBirchmeier. Yeah it seems I misunderstood that. I just pulled the value from the header and it works as expected, without adding to the `ExecutionReport` message. Please post this as an answer and I will mark it as the solution